# Find mean for sorted top n transactions

Tags: r

Let my dataframe has 2 columns, **customer id** & **transaction amount**. Now for each unique customer id i would like to find the transaction amount(sorted in descending order) & then from the sorted column i will find the mean transaction amount for top three transactions of the sorted list.

```
Cust_id     trans_amount
12345          100      
12345          200      
12345          170      
12345          300      
12345          250
12456          140        
12456          240       
12456          160       
12456          100
```

The format i am looking for is,

```
Cust_id     trans_amount
12345          300               
12345          250      
12345          200      
12345          170      
12345          100
12456          240        
12456          160       
12456          140       
12456          100
```

and from there the mean for top 3, ie,

```
Cust_id    mean_for_top_3
12345         250
12456         180
```

for the intermediate part,I have tried,

```
ddply(cust_data,.(cust_id.),summarize,sorted_amount=sort(trans_amount,,decreasing=TRUE))
```

but not getting the result. Please advise how can i reach to my desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(cust_data)
cust_data_sort <- cust_data[, .(trans_amount = sort(trans_amount, decreasing = TRUE)), Cust_id]
cust_data_sort[, .(mean_for_top_3 = mean(head(trans_amount, 3))), Cust_id]
   Cust_id mean_for_top_3
1:   12345            250
2:   12456            180
```

If you don't need sorted table `cust_data_sort`, then you can do get mean using this:

```
cust_data[, .(mean_for_top_3 = mean(head(sort(trans_amount, decreasing = TRUE), 3))), Cust_id]
```

Comment: yes it did work & I upvoted your answer. If i have to find means for the unique combination of two columns, how can I modify your code? I mean if my data had a 'month' column & i will try to find the mean for top 3 transactions for each unique cust id & month, where should I put the 'month' column in this code?

Comment: @HindolGanguly you should replace `, Cost_Id]` with `, .(month, Cost_Id]` and it should work. You can accept my answer if it helped to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic solution using `dplyr`

```
df <- read.table(text = "Cust_id     trans_amount
12345          100      
                 12345          200      
                 12345          170      
                 12345          300      
                 12345          250
                 12456          140        
                 12456          240       
                 12456          160       
                 12456          100    ", header  = T)


library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Cust_id) %>% 
  arrange(desc(trans_amount), .by_group = T) %>%
  top_n(n = 3) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(trans_amount))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Cust_id  mean
    <int> <dbl>
1   12345   250
2   12456   180
```

Alternative with count:

```
  > df %>% group_by(Cust_id) %>% 
+   #arrange(desc(trans_amount), .by_group = T) %>% 
+   mutate(count = n()) %>%
+   top_n(n = 3, wt = trans_amount) %>%
+   mutate(mean = mean(trans_amount)) %>%
+   select(Cust_id,mean,count) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Cust_id [2]
  Cust_id  mean count
    <int> <dbl> <int>
1   12345   250     5
2   12456   180     4
>
```

Comment: How the above code will be modified if along with mean, I also need to find the count of transactions too? I mean the output will be,

`Cust_id    mean_top_3   trans_count
 12345           250                 5
 12456           180                 4
`

Comment: No, the counts will be as in the original data, just like for 12345 it was 5 & for 12456 it was 4

Comment: Your code raising an error though
`Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incorrect size (1), expecting : 50000`
50000 is the length of my data

Comment: The error is with the current code or when you add count?

Comment: Did you give trans_amount in quotes?

Comment: Please try the alternative solution posted now

Comment: Alternative worked..but resulting two columns as before, not the transaction counts

Comment: Please provide me one suggestion, if I try to add more columns (just like i did try to add the count column), shall I use `mutate` accordingly for it just in the same fashion you did?

Comment: yes, ```mutate``` is better in this case rather than summarize and then you can ```select``` the columns you want and ```distinct``` it

Comment: Cool. Please mark as answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: I am sorry to say but the edited/alternative version only resulting the unique customer id's, neither mean nor the counts

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking at the latest one, for me it generates 3 columns.